# How to match one character plus space with PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Inside my text I have this output:

> Å apat

I want to search for 'Å ', note Å + space. and Convert it to 'Š'.

So basically I want to find this letter followed with space and replace it with just one letter without space.

String replace can not do this, and I am not very good with regex, I have tried this but it does not work:

```
$return = preg_replace('/[Å\s]/', 'Š', $return);
```

Can someone help me please ?

**NOTE:** this word "Å apat" does not have to be at the start of sentence, most of the time it is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Why can't str_replace do this?

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue to me. Search replacement is not a solution but only a source for more, harder, problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$re = "/Å\\s/m";
$str = "Å apat";
$subst = "Š";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

This should do it for you.[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/1)

Comment: Nothing happens... Everything stays the same after applying this regexp.

Comment: @black-room-boy see demo.it works.`$result` will be the updated string

Comment: Yeah example works, but it does not help me when I apply it to text coming from database. It seems encodings are messed up or something. Thanks for helping.

Comment: from php website "__`str_replace` will just replace a fixed string with another fixed string, and it will be much faster than `preg_replace`.__"

Comment: @black-room-boy: try to replace the m modifier (that is useless here) with the u modifier that tells the regex engine it deals with a unicode string. if you choose to use a litteral replacement (without regex and with a literal space), use `mb_str_replace` with the appropriate encoding.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte : no luck :(

Comment: @black-room-boy: the first step is to find how datas are encoded in your database. without this information you can't do anything. Try to use `mb_detect_encoding` to do that: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-detect-encoding.php and check your database/table/column setting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to solve an encoding problem (and probably only a display problem) with a string replacement.

It's not the way to go!

Let's see what happens:

If you looks at your string with an hex viewer you will find this hex sequence: C5 A0

But depending of the context, this sequence can be interpreted in two different ways:

C5 A0 = Š (C5A0 in utf8 encoding) = Å (C5 in unicode) + NO-BREAK SPACE (A0 in unicode)

So it seems that the problem is that your string is displayed as a sequence of unicode code points instead of a utf8 encoded string.

I assume that the problem comes from the html page that hasn't the good encoding information. Try to add information about the page encoding between head tags:

- html5: `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`
- html4: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Link: [chartable with unicode code point and utf8 encoding](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
$result = preg_replace('/Å /', 'Š', $text);
```

---

What your regex `[Å\s]` does is:
Match a the character Å or any whitespace character and replace it with Š

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regex here, use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
$string = "Å apat";
echo str_replace("Å ", "Š", $string);
//Šapat
```

Demo:

https://ideone.com/EXrwgW